# HTML/JS Form being submitted twice

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, submit

I am using node.js/express to create a webpage.

I currently have a form with some input and a submit button which is trigger by the click of another button currently on the page

This is the code for my form:

```
 <form name= "form" id="form-id" action="http://localhost:1337/process_post" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="hiddentext" id="textarea"/>
   <input hidden type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submit_button"/>
</form>
```

This is my button (which triggers the submit for the form to be clicked during the onclick event)

```
  <INPUT type="button" id="button-id" value="Save" onclick="this.disabled=true;load_page('form-id')" />
```

This is my JS script to click the submit button

```
 function load_page(formId){
        document.getElementById("submit_button").click();
      }
```

The issue I have is that the form is being submitted twice. I am unsure why this happens and how to fix the issue. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `return false` in your `onclick` attribute so as to prevent the default action, which is to submit the form (which you're already doing). Like this:

```
<INPUT type="button" id="button-id" value="Save" onclick="this.disabled=true;load_page('form-id');return false;" />
```

Comment: Do you mean function load_page(formId){
        document.getElementById("submit_button").click(function(){return false;});
      } because this does not work